# различия copy и deepcopy

Tags: python, python-3.x, library, copy

В чем заключаются различия между `copy` и `deepcopy` в питоне. Везде говорят, что из-за того, что `copy`, в отличие от `deepcopy`, копирует ссылки на объекты, а не их копии, какое то изменение во втором объекте влечет за собой изменения в первом. То есть, например, если у нас есть список `a = [1, 2, 3]`, и мы сделаем его `copy`, получится такой же список `b = [1, 2, 3]`. Но если изменить что-то в `b`, то оно изменится и в `а`, т. е., если, к примеру, `b[0] = 2`. То получится `b = [2, 2, 3]`, и `a = [2, 2, 3]`, т. к. `b` содержит именно ссылки на объекты. А `deepcopy` как-бы развязывает эти 2 списка. То есть, если `b[0] = 2`, то `b = [2, 2, 3]`, но `a = [1, 2, 3]`, т. к. `b` содержит именно копии, а не ссылки. Так вот я сейчас проверил эти гипотезы, и вышло, что и в случае `copy`, и в случае `deepcopy` изменения в `b`, не влекут за собой изменения в `a`, хотя везде говорят, что и `a` должен измениться, ведь он содержит ссылки объекта `a`. Так в чем-же все таки различия между `copy` и `deepcopy` в питоне. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто гляньте на эти пару примеров, все станет понятно.

```
    >>> a = [1,2,3]
    >>> b = a
    >>> b[0] = 5
    >>> a, b
    ([5, 2, 3], [5, 2, 3])
    >>> a = [1,2,3]
    >>> b = a.copy()
    >>> b[0] = 5
    >>> a, b
    ([1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 3])
    >>> a = [1,2,[3,4,5]]
    >>> b = a.copy()
    >>> b[2][0] = 10
    >>> a, b
    ([1, 2, [10, 4, 5]], [1, 2, [10, 4, 5]])
    >>> from copy import deepcopy
    >>> a = [1,2,[3,4,5]]
    >>> b = deepcopy(a)
    >>> b[2][0] = 10
    >>> a, b
    ([1, 2, [3, 4, 5]], [1, 2, [10, 4, 5]])
```

Comment: Так получается это работает только если список - это как бы вложенные отрезки, то есть если список состоит из списков. А если у нас, например, просто список состоящий из 5 чисел, выходит в таком списке нет различий между copy и deepcopy?

Comment: Да, нету. Deepcopy в отличие от простого copy копирует ссылки вложенных объектов тоже.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо!