# Цикл for в функции работает только один раз

Tags: python

недавно стал программировать на питоне. Решил сделать задачу на палиндром, цель задачи в том чтобы программа с помощью цикла фор удаляла из списка букв слова одну букву и проверяла получается ли из этого слова палиндром.Почему то цикл работает только одну итерацию и дальше не хочет.Программа немного не доработана.

```
def OneToPalindrome(obj):
    for letter in obj:
        popped = obj
        popped.pop(obj.index(letter))
        revobj = popped[-1::-1]
        if revobj == obj:
            print('True')
            break
        else:
            revobj.clear()
            popped.clear() 
            #здесь будет счетчик итераций

OneToPalindrome(obj = list(input().lower()))
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1201225

Comment: @user207200, это к чему? Тут вложенных списков вроде нет.

Comment: @Глеб в ответе приведены как примеры копирования так и причины его необходимости

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
>>> def one_to_palindrome(lst):
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            lst2 = lst[:]
            lst2.pop(i)
            if lst2 == lst2[::-1]:
                return True
        return False

>>> one_to_palindrome(list('aaab'))
True
>>> one_to_palindrome(list('hudsfdsii'))
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Судя по коду вы предполагаете что `popped = obj` создаёт копию списка. Это не так: обе переменные ссылаются на один и тот же список. Когда позже вы удаляете символ, исходный список портится, дальнейшая работа не имеет смысла.

Если исправить на `popped = obj[:]`, то будет копирование. Тогда вылезет ошибка в `if revobj == obj:`. Сравниваются строки разной длинны, равенства не будет никогда.

Если исправить на `if revobj == popped:`, то заработает. Тогда вылезет ошибка в `popped.pop(obj.index(letter))`. Всегда будет удалятся первая буква из нескольких одинаковых. Это явно не то что вам нужно.

Можно перебирать индексы вместо букв. Получится что-то такое:

```
def OneToPalindrome(obj):
    for i in range(len(obj)):
        popped = obj[:]
        popped.pop(i)
        revobj = popped[-1::-1]
        if revobj == obj:
            print('True')
            break
        else:
            revobj.clear()
            popped.clear() 
            #здесь будет счетчик итераций

OneToPalindrome(obj = list(input().lower()))
```

**P.S.** Если вы доведете решение до ума, то получится квадратичная сложность. Задачу можно решить намного быстрее, за линейное время.